# Android file access issue

Tags: java, android, audio, permissions

I am attempting to save recorded audio from an application to the storage device using MediaRecorder.

When I used internal storage (/data/data/com.example.app/files) I got random MediaRecorder errors. These errors were resolved by changing the save location to

```
String files_dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myapp_audiofolder/";
```

This works fine except that other applications have access to this folder. For instance, my Google Music app included the audio from this folder in the music listings.

What is the proper way to store data like this so only my application will have access to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android documentation has a page dedicated to data storage, and here you can find the section on using the [internal storage to save application data](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal). As long as you call `FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` with the `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` parameter as shown in their example, only your app will be able to access the file.

Comment: I had tried using this before, but I ran into issue because the MeidaRecorder's setOutputFile() takes a string parameter. Is there a way around this? This is the general [code](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html) I've been following

Comment: I looked in the [MediaRecorder documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setOutputFile(java.io.FileDescriptor)) and it says that you can also call `setOutputFile` with a `FileDescriptor`, so you could call something like `setOutputFile(fos.getFD())` (where `fos` is the `FileOutputStream` in my answer)

Comment: thanks! getFD() did the trick. Playing the file uses a similar format: FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(filename); then mplayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());

Comment: Glad I could help. If your problem is all solved then you could accept the answer so other people know the question is answered.